# Обращение в файлу с расширением bin в asp .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

У меня есть asp . net core проект.
Я хочу сохранять данные в bin файл в одном месте, а в другом к нему обращаться.
Я сохраняю его в папке `Resources\data.bin` в своём проекте, и затем обращаюсь к нему по вот такому пути: `string _filePath = @"..\Resources\data.bin"`, но не могу до него добраться.
подскажите, может я не так к нему обращаюсь или может вообще этого нельзя делать?

Comment: Попробуйте не относительный, а абсолютный путь. И что значит "не можете добраться"?

Comment: Я когда вызываю контроллер, который использует этот файл, то сервер вот такое выдаёт: The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

Comment: @ГеннадийП абсолютный - это когда "C:\\......"?

Comment: @ГеннадийП приложение у меня на azure

Comment: Путь начинается от места запуска экзешника, вот от туда и вычитают пути, например `..\\..\\..\\Resource\\my.bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя немного времени задача решена таким образом:
В приложении имеется три проекта, два из них называются Client и Server (они автоматически создаются при создании приложения blazor). В Client есть папка wwwroot, в которой хранятся ресурсы. Вот я в ней создал папку Resources и кинул в неё этот бинарник.
Затем опубликовал на azure, там папки и файлы из папки wwwroot помещаются в папку dist и вот туда собственно путь я и прописал.

До этого по не знанию я создавал в проекте Server папку Resources и путь прописывал до неё.
Возможно как-то и из неё можно использовать файлы, но я не знаю как.